# Extractor: inferred type arguments X do not conform to method unapply's type parameter bounds

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-bounds

In the following example, Scala cannot use the extractor, and it is driving me mad:

```
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]]

object Element {
  object Foo {
    def unapply[S <: Sys[S]](foo: Foo[S]): Option[Any] = ???
  }
  trait Foo[S <: Sys[S]] extends Element[S]
}
trait Element[S <: Sys[S]]
```

This is a test case:

```
def test[S <: Sys[S]](elem: Element[S]) = elem match {
  case Element.Foo(_) => ???
  case _ => ???
}
```

Failing with

```
inferred type arguments [S] do not conform to method unapply's type parameter
  bounds [S <: Sys[S]]
```

(both in Scala 2.9.2 and 2.10).

---

If I remove the F-bound it works:

```
trait Sys

object Element {
  object Foo {
    def unapply[S <: Sys](foo: Foo[S]): Option[Any] = ???
  }
  trait Foo[S <: Sys] extends Element[S]
}
trait Element[S <: Sys]

def test[S <: Sys](elem: Element[S]) = elem match {
  case Element.Foo(_) => ???
  case _ => ???
}
```

I guess this is one of those "hate Scala days". Can this be so stupid? Basically it is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709182/scala-compiler-cannot-infer-mix-in-type-for-pattern-matching), which doesn't have a proper answer.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem but when nesting two extractors. It seems they've fixed the first-level extraction issue but nesting such as case Foo(x, Bar(y, z)) where Bar has an unapply with an F-bound, you get this error. It is supremely frustrating. :(

Answer (score -2):

When trying call a `test` with `null` argument and `Sys[Any]` type parameter, it does said that:

```
type arguments [Sys[Any]] do not conform to trait Element's type parameter 
  bounds [S <: Sys[S]]
```

Trying variance:

```
trait Sys[-S]

object Element {
  object Foo {
    def unapply[S <: Sys[S]](foo: Foo[S]): Option[Any] = ???
  }
  trait Foo[S <: Sys[S]] extends Element[S]
}
trait Element[S <: Sys[S]]

def test[S <: Sys[S]](elem: Element[S]) = elem match {
  case f: Element.Foo[S] => "ok"
  case _ => "smth else"
}

// test
test(new Element.Foo[Sys[Any]](){})  // "smth else"
test(new Element[Sys[Any]](){})      // "ok"
```